# CTimeSpan always gets zero

Tags: c++, ctime, elapsedtime

I am trying to get the running time of Insertion Sort Algorithm. MSDN said that using CTime could get the Elapsed Time. But I tried many times and always got zero. I thought it is impossible that the time of running this algorithm is zero. There must be some error or something else. Could anybody help me? I posted my code below:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <atltime.h> 
using namespace std;
//member function
void insertion_sort(int arr[], int length);
int *create_array(int arrSize);

int main() {
    //Create random array
    int arraySize=100;
    int *randomArray=new int[arraySize];
    int s;
    for (s=0;s<arraySize;s++){
        randomArray[s]=(rand()%99)+1;
    }

    CTime startTime = CTime::GetCurrentTime();

    int iter;
    for (iter=0;iter<1000;iter++){
        insertion_sort(randomArray,arraySize);
    }

    CTime endTime = CTime::GetCurrentTime();
    CTimeSpan elapsedTime = endTime - startTime;
    double nTMSeconds = elapsedTime.GetTotalSeconds()*1000;
    cout<<nTMSeconds;
    return 0;
}//end of main
```

Comment: `CTime` has a resolution of one second. Apparently, your whole test takes less than a second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CTime isn't meant to time things to a resolution less than one second. I think what you are really after is something like `GetTickCount` or `GetTickCount64` . See this MSDN [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724408(v=vs.85).aspx) .

> GetTickCount function
>
> Retrieves the number of milliseconds that have elapsed since the system was started, up to 49.7 days.

If using `GetTickCount64` you could declare `startTime` and `endTime` this way:

```
uint64_t endTime, startTime, diffTime;
```

Then use `GetTickCount64` to retrieve the time in milliseconds with something like

```
startTime = GetTickCount64();
... do stuff ...
endTime = GetTickCount64();

diffTime = endTime - startTime;
```

And of course diffTime can be used however you want.

If you don't need to time things for more than a month then you can simply use `GetTickCount` and the type returned will be a `uint32_t` instead of `uint64_t`

If you need resolution beyond 1 millisecond for timing and your computer supports a high resolution timer then this code may work:

```
LARGE_INTEGER freq;
double time_sec = 0.0;

if (QueryPerformanceFrequency(&freq))
{
    LARGE_INTEGER start;
    LARGE_INTEGER stop;

    QueryPerformanceCounter(&start);

    // Do Stuff to time Here

    QueryPerformanceCounter(&stop);
    time_sec = (uint64_t)(stop.QuadPart - start.QuadPart) / (double)freq.QuadPart;
}
else {
    cout << "Your computer doesn't have a high resolution timer to use";
}
```

Information on the high performance timer can be found in this MSDN [entry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644905(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: I tried it but still not work. I checked the value of the start time and the end time. They were the same. Therefore, the diffTime is still zero.

Comment: Its not that it isn't working. Whatever you are timing is less than the resolution of the timer being used. If get tickcount produces 0 it means that whatever you are timing is less than 1 millisecond(1/1000th of a second). I have provided one last mechanism (I added it to my answer) but it won't work on some computer systems without a high resolution timer. If you have a timer this will be the best you can get.