# prevent instruction reordering when profiling a piece of code

Tags: c++, profiling, instruction-reordering

Is there a standard way to prevent code reordering when profiling functions in c++? Let's say I have a code like this

```
void foo() {
    const auto timeStart = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    // code that we want to profile.....
    const auto timeEnd = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::cout << "Took " << (timeEnd - timeStart).count() << "\n";
}
```

Compiler is free to reorder the instructions if there is no side effect. In this case timeStart does not get used till the very end. Can compiler rearrange the function to something like -

```
void foo() {
    // code that we want to profile.....
    const auto timeStart = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    const auto timeEnd = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::cout << "Took " << (timeEnd - timeStart).count() << "\n";
}
```

If yes, then how to prevent the reordering of instructions around timeStart, or timeEnd? Is using full memory barrier the only option? Where exactly do we need to insert the barrier- do we insert the barrier before and after the timestart and before and after the timeEnd?

Thanks

Comment: Related:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/26195437/4706785

Comment: Totally unrelated: `system_clock` probably isn't the best clock for this job. It can be corrected by outside sources during the test ruining the results. `steady_clock` is usually the better tool for this job.

Comment: By adding timing code to your code you will modify the behavior of your code. Move foo to a static library and use that in a test executable  to test the perfomance of foo in isolation.  E.g. [nanobench](https://nanobench.ankerl.com/tutorial.html) a small header file only library. In the end you will have to test the perfomance in your product and then you need to use a full profiler.

Comment: @user4581301 You are absolutely right, the reason being system_clock is not guaranteed to be monotonic. It can actually go back in time (when your system synchronizes with an NTP server for example)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it legal for a C++ optimizer to reorder calls to clock()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26190364/is-it-legal-for-a-c-optimizer-to-reorder-calls-to-clock)

Comment: There are conflicting statements. The best answer says it's not possible for compiler to reorder. But a similar thread - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37786547/enforcing-statement-order-in-c?noredirect=1&lq=1 says it'cant be stopped unless you include DoNotOptimize. I am still not sure what's the best way to achieve the ordered execution.